# How to parse a string with comma-separated elements that can include strings?

Tags: antlr4

I need to parse a string with comma-separated values where some of the values can be strings. Something like this
`"fubar, 1, 1.2, "snafu""`.
The nested strings are killing me.

This is what I have

```
grammar snafu;

// ignore embedded newlines (escaped) and whitespace.
ESC_NEWLINE :  '\\' '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
WS          :  [ \t]+ -> skip;

D_QUOTE    :  '"' ;
COMMA      :  ',' ;

ID         :  (LETTER|'_') (LETTER|DIGIT|'_')* ;
INTEGER    :  '0' | ('-'? NON_ZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*);
FLOAT      :  '-'? ( '0' '.' DIGIT+ | NON_ZERO_DIGIT DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+) ;
STRING     :  D_QUOTE ( ~["\\]+ |  ESCAPE_SEQUENCE )* D_QUOTE ;

fragment LETTER          :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT           :  ('0' | NON_ZERO_DIGIT);
fragment NON_ZERO_DIGIT  :  [1-9] ;
fragment ESCAPE_SEQUENCE :  '\\' ( [nrtbf()\\] | [0-7] [0-7] [0-7] ) ;

number : INTEGER | FLOAT ;

string : STRING ;

csv_string_value :  number | ID | string ;
csv_string : D_QUOTE csv_string_value (COMMA csv_string_value)* D_QUOTE;
A
```

ll is well with parsing "foo" with the 'string' rule but I would hope that it would parse as an "ID" using the 'csv_string' rule. Instead, it parses as a 'string' with an error that the first D_QUOTE in csv_string is missing.

I don't understand why this doesn't work.  Do I need to create modes and push and pop when I encounter D_QUOTE?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess the problem is the Lexer runs first. It has no notion of csv_string, only STRING. So it turns everything into a STRING, eating '"' that the parser needs.

Answer (score 0):

Lexer rules can be recursive. Try this:

```
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"] | '\\' . | STRING )* '"';
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: With "bar, 1, "foo"", I get

oops. I can't attach image of parse tree.
What I'm shooting for is something like

                            csv_string
    |           |               |                 |           |
D_QOUTE csv_string_value csv_string_value csv_string_value D_QUOTE
                |                |                 |
             ID: bar       number: 1         string: "foo"

Bummer, no formatting is all gone.

Comment: Works on my machine :). I don't know what "I get oops" means. You could edit your original question and include enough of the grammar to reproduce the problem.