# What tokens should be emitted when entering and exiting different lexer modes in ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

My example is strings within strings, like "foo, 1, 1.2, "fubar"".  I feel like a token could be emitted for every '"'. First encounter with '"' emits OPEN_CSV_STRING but the second encounter either opens an embedded-string mode to handle "fubar" or closes the csv-string mode. The lexer can't know without looking ahead.  How does one handle this situation?
One has to consume the input somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lexer rule can be recursive, like I showed in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878264/how-to-parse-a-string-with-comma-separated-elements-that-can-include-strings). But when allowing for (unescaped) embedded strings, you cannot tell the difference between 2 separate strings, or 1 string with 1 embedded string:

```
… “ … “ … “ … “ …
  ————-   —————      2 strings
  ————————————-      1 string
```

In the example above, how would you tell the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This does what I need.

```
lexer grammar Filter_Lexer;

WS : ([ \t]+ | '\\' '\r'? '\n') -> skip;

OPEN_CSV_STRING: '"'  -> pushMode(CSV_STRING_MODE) ;

ID      :  (LETTER|'_') (LETTER|DIGIT|'_')* ;
INTEGER :  '0' | ('-'? NON_ZERO_DIGIT DIGIT*);
FLOAT   :  '-'? ( '0' '.' DIGIT+ | NON_ZERO_DIGIT DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+) ;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT  : ('0' | NON_ZERO_DIGIT);
fragment NON_ZERO_DIGIT : [1-9] ;

mode CSV_STRING_MODE ;
WS1 : ([ \t]+ | '\\' '\r'? '\n') -> skip;
ID_EL : ID;
IN_EL : INTEGER;
FL_EL : FLOAT;
CSV_COMMA : ',' ;
OPEN_STRING: '"'  -> pushMode(STRING_MODE) ;

mode STRING_MODE ;
STRING_VAL :  ~["]+ ;
CLOSE_STRING : '"'  -> popMode ;

parser grammar Filter;

options { tokenVocab=Filter_Lexer; }   

csv_string_element: OPEN_STRING STRING_VAL CLOSE_STRING ;
csv_string : OPEN_CSV_STRING  (ID_EL | IN_EL | FL_EL | csv_string_element | CSV_COMMA)* OPEN_STRING EOF ;
```

This gives up on the notion of emitting a close-csv-string token for the last '"' and instead just uses the open-string token.
This parses "foo, 1, 1.2, "snafu", bar" into the ID_EL, IN_EL, FL_EL, and STRING_VAL tokens. This works because I know where the csv-strings start and embedded strings can't have embedded strings.

Comment: But now the last `"` (the one after `bar`) is tokenized as a `OPEN_STRING`, which is not correct I presume. I don't know where the source originates from, but if possible, it is probably a better idea to have that source produce valid CSV instead of what you're trying to handle now. You can then use a proven CSV library instead of having to roll your own.

Comment: Exactly. That last `OPEN_STRING` is not correct, which is why I was fixated on generating a `CLOSE_CSV_STRING` token.  Which is impossible unless the search is to `EOF` and there is a mechanism to fall back to the last occurrence of `'"'`. Or if you know that the last occurrence is always at the end of a line, `CLOSE_CSV_STRING : '"' NEWLINE ;`